# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' while installing Keras for anaconda3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After installing 'Keras' library (pip install keras) when I try to import keras in jupyter notebook I get an error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. Kindly suggest for the workaround. Seems to be an know issue but couldn't get any correct answers

Answer (score 0):

`keras` and `tensorflow` are separate packages and Keras as a library does not depend on `tensorflow`. If you would like to use Keras with Tensorflow, you need to also install `tensorflow`:

```
pip install keras tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna install tensorflow for anaconda try (from https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow)

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

or with gpu support (from https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu)

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

And Keras switched to `tensorflow.keras`, which is a part of tensorflow>=1.10.0 (no need to install Keras separettly)